# How to fetch records for a specific date from Core Data Persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an Entity with a date property. I want to fetch records for a specific date. How?

Here is code:

```
NSDate *dateToFetch = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == <What Next?>"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
NSArray *filtered  = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSPredicate syntax has a keyword "BETWEEN". Make the first date 00:00:00 on that day with NSDateComponents and the second date 11:59:59.